# How do I use @CheckForNull etc with Findbugs?

Tags: java, eclipse, null, annotations, findbugs

When I run this through Findbugs, I get a warning:

```
static @NonNull Object foo(@CheckForNull Object arg) {
    if (arg == null) { // warning on this line
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return "something";

}
```

The details of the warning is the following:

> Bug: `arg` must be nonnull but is marked as nullable
>   Pattern id: `NP_PARAMETER_MUST_BE_NONNULL_BUT_MARKED_AS_NULLABLE`, type: `NP`, category: `STYLE`
>
> This parameter is always used in a way that requires it to be nonnull, but the parameter is explicitly annotated as being `Nullable`. Either the use of the parameter or the annotation is wrong.

Can someone explain what Findbugs is complaining about here?

Note that I'm using the `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.*` members, not the `javax.annotations.*`. (Is there a difference?)

Set up is FindBugs plug-in 1.3.9.2009- for Eclipse 3.6.1.

---

Matthew Flaschen suggested that I use `@NonNull` instead, but now I ran into this problem:

```
static void blah(@NonNull Object arg) {
    if (arg == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    System.out.println(arg);
}

static @CheckForNull Object bleh() {
    return null;
}

//...
blah(bleh()); // warning here!
```

The details of the warning is:

> Bug: Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method
>   Pattern id: `NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE`, type: `NP`, category: `STYLE`
>
> The return value from a method is dereferenced without a `null` check, and the return value of that method is one that should generally be checked for `null`. This may lead to a `NullPointerException` when the code is executed.

I basically want `blah` to satisfy the `@CheckForNull` requirement, but I can't do it if I make its arg be `@NonNull`. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 5):

You're contradicting yourself.  [`CheckForNull`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/annotations/CheckForNull.html) means, "The annotated element might be null", but if it is you immediately throw.

If it's never acceptable for a caller to pass null, I believe you should instead annotate it:

```
static @NonNull Object foo(@NonNull Object arg) {
```

Comment: Won't annotating it as `@NonNull` cause a problem when you are comparing it with `arg == null` because Findbugs thinks it's unnecessary?

Comment: @poly, no, I tested.  It only warns when you mark the parameter `CheckForNull`.  It accepts no annotation or `NonNull`.  This makes sense, since the `NonNull` alone does not enforce itself.